# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using WAMP server 2 on Windows 7 64 bit.

As I enter in **phpmyadmin** with user root, it shows error:

> " #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO)"

If I change user name then it allow me to show the **phpmyadmin** page.

If I create database then it is showing me an error:

> " #1044 - Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'family' "

and said at least one privilege is needed.

So what can I do?

I change the config.ini.php file but problem is persisting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The user ''@'localhost' in your message, is an anonymous user (listed as Any in phpMyAdmin's Users panel). Delete this user which is causing you trouble. In, in phpMyAdmnin 4.5 we will add a warning about this account definition.